# sbt: Unable to specify application configuration in mingw

Tags: scala, mingw, sbt, msys

I am trying to launch an application using sbt's [application launcher](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/GeneralizedLauncher).
This application is defined as:

```
#!/bin/sh  
java -jar /home/salil.wadnerkar/.conscript/sbt-launch.jar @"/home/salil.wadnerkar/.conscript/n8han/conscript/cs/launchconfig" "$@"
```

However, when I launch it, it gives me this error:

```
$ ~/bin/cs n8han/giter8  
Error during sbt execution: Could not find configuration file 'C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/salil.wadnerkar/.conscript/n8han/conscript/cs/launchconfig'.  Searched:
    file:/C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/salil.wadnerkar/
    file:/C:/Users/salil.wadnerkar/
    file:/C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/salil.wadnerkar/.conscript/
```

However, the file is present there. So, I think it's because of some quirk in the way sbt handles mingw file path.
Does anybody know how I can get it working?

Comment: I am having the same issue with Play2.0 on the MSYS shell.

Comment: The top voted answer worked for me, maybe it shoulde be marked as answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Cygwin I used

```
java -jar "`cygpath -m "$HOME/.conscript/sbt-launch.jar"`" "@file:///C:/Users/cvanvranken/.conscript/n8han/conscript/cs/launchconfig" "$@"
```

I expect you will be able to get yours to work with something similar, perhaps this:

```
java -jar /home/salil.wadnerkar/.conscript/sbt-launch.jar "@file:///C:/Users/salil.wadnerkar/.conscript/n8han/conscript/cs/launchconfig" "$@"
```

or

```
java -jar /home/salil.wadnerkar/.conscript/sbt-launch.jar "@file:///C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/salil.wadnerkar/.conscript/n8han/conscript/cs/launchconfig" "$@"
```

**if those fail, you still definitely need to use the file:// protocol.**

Also note the three directories it is searching in the error message

```
file:/C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/salil.wadnerkar/
file:/C:/Users/salil.wadnerkar/
file:/C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/salil.wadnerkar/.conscript/
```

no matter what you put in the launchconfig parameter, if it is not recognized then those directories are searched by default.  So you could have gibberish in your parameter and still see the same exact error you are getting now.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the launch config path relative to the .conscript folder -

```
java -jar /home/salil.wadnerkar/.conscript/sbt-launch.jar @n8han/conscript/cs/launchconfig "$@"
```